# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). when creating a WP_query

Tags: wp-query, php

I came across this nice way of showing a list of posts. It works fine as long as I use the *"category"* **taxonomy**. When that changes, it still works but an annoying message displays in the background.

It is suppossed to get the *slug* of the **taxonomies** associated with the post and add them to the *class* of the *div*

*Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()* . On the line the foreach is located.

Thank You.

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'service' ); ?>
  <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

      <div id="post-list">

          <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

                    $termsString = ""; 
                    $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "service" );

                      foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) {
                          $termsString .= $term->slug.' ';
                      }  
          ?>

                <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> item"></div>

                <?php endwhile;  ?>
       </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved., little things matter.

```
if ($termsArray) {

  foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) {
    $termsString .= $term->slug.' ';
  }  

}
```